# Costura.Fody nuget package rolls back when installing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fody, fody-costura

I started a new c# .net Framework 4.8 console project with no code. I tried to install Costura.Fody nuget package. The installation starts to install as expected but then once it hits System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0 the install starts to roll back. It uninstalls and I get an error message stating:
[image]

I checked the folder in the error message and there is no System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll in the folder. I checked another Visual Studio project where I have Costrua.Fody installed correctly and functioning, and that file does exist. I would suspect the file is created / downloaded when the nuget package is installed.

I did a second test. I tried referencing a DLL into the project and it copied local as expected. I tried installing Costura.Fody again and got this error message:
[image]
Visual studio askes me to restart to finish the process. After restarting Visual Studio, I tried for a third time to install Costura.Fody, and again it rolls back once it get to System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0

I searched for similar issues but couldn't find anything. Any idea why this is failing?
I am using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise on windows 11